# Mail delivery problems

Tags: ubuntu, logs, postfix, sendmail

Once upon a time there was a server. Lets call it zzz.com, running Ubuntu LTS 10.
Then, domain owner decided to create his corporate mail via Google Apps, and created account username@zzz.com.

Everything looks to be fine with username@zzz.com. Mail is sent / received.

But there is one mysterious problem. When PHP script at zzz.com is trying to send some mail to [ANYNAME]@zzz.com, mail is not delivered. Sendmail works fine when trying to send mail anywhere else.

There is a non-delivery notification in this case in the mail log.

What could this be? How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds to be almost exactly the same issue than [on ServerFault question titled Disable local delivery in sendmail](https://serverfault.com/questions/65365/disable-local-delivery-in-sendmail).

The solution is to disable the local delivery of mail with the following steps:

1. Open one of the sendmail's configuration files, `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc`, using any editor you want (I use vim as an example):

   ```
   vim /etc/mail/sendmail.mc
   ```
2. Add the following lines to the end of the file:

   ```
   define(`MAIL_HUB', `zzz.com.')dnl
   define(`LOCAL_RELAY', `zzz.com.')dnl
   ```
3. Configure sendmail:

   ```
   sudo sendmailconfig
   ```
4. Restart the `sendmail` service:

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/sendmail restart
   ```

   or

   ```
   service sendmail restart
   ```

#### References

- [Disable local delivery in sendmail](https://serverfault.com/a/128450/197045)